# WordPress CPT custom custom label

Tags: custom-post-types

I want to edit the html output of the CPT page. Searched a lot but didn't find a solution ... May be I'm searching it wrong or it not might have done by anyone yet.

[image]

In the screenshot above one can clearly see the title Contest which is a label when I registered this post type. Its generating in `<h1>` tag. Either I want to edit the output or add a new element (i.e. and image) above it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add anything up there with the 'in_admin_header' action. Example (pseudo code):

```
add_action( 'in_admin_header', function() {
    if ( ... check $post_type, $pagenow etc, to target right page only ... ) {
        echo '<p>Hello editor</p>';
    }
} );
```